# Adding tooltip text to JLabel prevents containing JPanel from throwing MouseEvents

Tags: java, tooltip, mouseevent

I have a JPanel (`pNums`) which contains another JPanel (`pGrid`). `pGrid` itself contains a grid (`JLabel[][]` in a GridLayout) of labels. There is a mouse listener which catches events from `pGrid` and does fairly important stuff with them (as in, the entire functionality of the program relies on the mouseClicked() event). This works perfectly, exactly the way I wanted it to... until I add tooltips to the labels.

As soon as I call `JLabel.setToolTipText("SomeString")` the listener stops reacting to events (I have tried most, if not all of the mouse events, none of them seem to be called).

I am *sure* that it is the tooltips by the way, commenting out the `setToolTipText()` completely fixes the problem. Of course, since I *needed* the tooltips, it also causes a whole host of other problems.

I've looked around and while I haven't found anything `quite` right, I get the impression that I just chose a really bad way to do what I wanted. But I also want to know for sure.

Can I get both the event and the tooltip or should I go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to "fix" this issue, with setting delay on tooltip appearance. But once it will appear user will have to click to hide it anyway.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html

The reson for this might be, that tooltip itself needs mouse click, to hide.